# Can I print something from a table using 2 sets of variables

Tags: python

I am having trouble being able to print reference something from a list by using 2 variables.

```
currentRow=4
currentRowText="row"+str(currentRow)
currentCol=3
currentLocType=currentRowText[currentCol]
print(currentRow,">",currentRowText,">",currentCol,">",currentLocType)
```

This prints out

```
4 > row4 > 3 > 4
```

however the last variable should be 'city' as it should be getting the data from

```
row4=("grasslands", "forest", "forest", "city", "forest", "forest", "mountain")
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the content of `currentRowText`

Comment: `currentRowText[currentCol]` gets the (3+1)st character of the string "row4", not the element at location 3 in the set named `row4`. How to get that depends on how you're storing your rows.

Comment: Thanks. The way that i am storing the rows is like above where i have row 4, there are rows row1-7, it is for a simple map based text game so this should be the last part i need to make it work (hopefully)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you should replace this:

```
currentLocType=currentRowText[currentCol]
```

With:

```
currentLocType=row4[currentCol]
```

`currentRowText` currently contains a string, not a reference to a variable. Maybe you mean to do something like:

```
currentLocType=eval(currentRowText)[currentCol]
```

Which means interpreting currentRowText's string as code. Using eval will turn `'row4'[currentCol]` into `row4[currentCol]`.
If this is what you intend to do, first read about the [disadvantages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/is-using-eval-in-python-a-bad-practice) of using `eval`.